# How can I check if the value is within the scope of the options in Codeigniter Form Validation?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a HTML form

```
<select name="country" id="country">
  <option value="PHL">Philippines</option>
  <option value="JPN">Japan</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
```

And I want to validate in my controller if the country is valid. For example, it should return error if the user enters a value that is not within the scope, which in my case: "Philippines", "Japan", "USA"

This is my code in my controller.

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('country','Country',array('required',array('country', array("PHL", "JPN", "USA"))));
```

Comment: You can use callback function to validate it
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: I did not realized that.  I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried the call back function but I have too many fields to validate. I am planning to create lots of functions but obviously, it is not efficient.

Comment: I have too many fields to validate ? What are others fields?